# NotifyDataSetChanged is not working when the field of some items in list is changed in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a Model `UniqueUserTransModel` and a `UniqueArrayList`. Initially, I have the List and I am passing it to the Adapter.

Old List ->

```
pos : 0, name : "user 1", transcount : 10
pos : 1, name : "user 2", transcount : 9
pos : 2, name : "user 3", transcount : 8
pos : 3, name : "user 4", transcount : 7
pos : 4, name : "user 5", transcount : 6
```

After Updating I have a `NewList` and I set it to UniqueArrayList = (newly Computed ArrayList).

New List ->

```
pos : 0, name : "user 2", transcount : 11
pos : 1, name : "user 1", transcount : 9
pos : 2, name : "user 3", transcount : 8
pos : 3, name : "user 4", transcount : 7
pos : 4, name : "user 5", transcount : 6
```

And I just called `notifydatasetChanged` from the Fragment.

The first two items get swapped in the `NewList` but are not reflecting in the recyclerview.

Why it is not reflecting? I know if I clear the old list and freshly add the new one it will work or if i add or remove a new Item then also it will work.

Comment: can you provide your adapter and fragment code???

Comment: It's complicated. That's y I put it like this. what do you want to know?

Comment: i want to know how you update your adapter's list

Comment: I use Realm and I need to do some computation so I take a Hashmap and do some computation like count the number of trans per user. So I increase the count and make a Hashmap and put all the values into an ArrayList. And now when a new trans I being made, the whole code re-run and I will get a newly updated list from the HashMap sorted by the no. of trans. Without clearing, I was just passing the ArrayList = (newly generated list from hmap), but the adapter was not changing.

Comment: it seems to be ok as you describe the process, but really not helpful to tell what's wrong in your code

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new Arraylist for Adapter.

Clear the arraylist and add all the items into it from new arraylist.

**Old ArrayList**

```
UniqueArrayList.clear()
```

**New Arraylist**

```
UniqueArrayList.addAll(**name of new arraylist**)
```

Now again reload the dataset.

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```